# Can't access into Windows 10 session after update

Tags: windows-10, login, pin

Last day I used Windows 10, Windows updated. A few days after updating (and no one had access to the computer), I tried to log in into my Windows 10 user session but I couldn't, I enter my login pin but Windows 10 keeps notifying me that pin is incorrect.

The problem is not the pin, because I write it correctly, the problem is *I can't login into my computer because "the pin is incorrect" when it is not.*

It seems that after the update, the pin has changed, so now I can't have access to my session.

I have tried changing the pin via the CMD of the repair mode, but I can't.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So switch to password mode and enter the password.

Comment: @Ramhound how I do that?

Comment: There is an icon on the login screen

Comment: same happened to me too few days back, luckily I had another guest account with password enable, try your password it will let you in with password I hope